# Scheduling events by the week of the month, COLDFUSION

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to create a function, in Coldfusion, that will create an event by the Week of the Month, rather than by the Day of the Month.

An example would be that the event should be scheduled every 2nd week of a month, rather than the 2nd Tuesday of a month.

However, I've come across the problem that months can have anywhere from 4 to 6 weeks, and if someone scheduled an event on the 5th or 6th week of the month, it wouldn't repeat in the months that don't have 5 or 6 weeks.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to approach the problem, so any brainstorming advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A week can be one of 7 days.  Do you want the event to take place every day of this week, or a specific day?

Comment: That's going to depend on a couple of things. Is the 1st of the month always in the first week? What if it's on a Sunday? Or a Saturday? Certainly you can work out how many weeks a month has by using the built-in [week](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/week.html) by comparing the week number returned for the 1st of the month to the week number returned for the last day of the month.

Comment: This sounds like it would be a good case for a date dimension table that can make calculations like these easier. You could set up the definition of every day for however long out you need. Then just join your data to the dimension table to get the results you need. Since they're so useful, I think all databases should have a date dimension table.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find the lowest common denominator and that is February. February has 28 days when not leap year. A week has 7 days and 4 x 7 = 28 so that means you can not provide a function that reliably allows for scheduling on week 5 (or 6, 7, 8, etc) of every month. One work around would be that if there is no logical day for the scheduled week that month then run the task on the final day of the month or the first day of the following. On the last day for example you can check for any tasks scheduled later in the month that can not be run and then run them.